# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js): Error: Emit

Tags: angular, angularjs

Build at: 2022-09-14T11:34:20.503Z - Hash: c51f599b4586fb6d - Time: 7780ms

./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit

Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - Cannot read properties of null (reading 'fileName')

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

× Failed to compile.

Comment: Hello guy, I am having this error on my project and I can;t find a solution online, maybe someone already experience this and might want to help. Thank in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have opened another question hoping that someone will be able to provide us with solution

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be an issue with Typescript version >4.9.0. I haven't worked out what that is yet, but a possible workaround is do amend your version to 4.8.2 if you can as this version doesn't seem to have that issue.

I'll post again if I find what exactly is causing the issue.

Comment: yes I confirm it is the version of Typescript that raised this error, when I installed EsLint there was an automatic update of Typescript from 4.7.4 to 4.9.3
but if i use you're version (4.8.2) i have the same error ...

Answer (score 6):

**Check this One, May be helpful**
Basic reason behind this can be... Recursive calls to some modules.

for e.g.

```
@NgModule({
     declarations: [],
     imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MaterialModule
     ],
     exports:[MatSliderModule]
    })
    export class MaterialModule { }
```

Here, Same **MaterialModule** is  importing self.
It increases the the call stack and results into the above mentioned error.

This is one condition. There can be other conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Try to find `node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/ngcc_lock_file`
file and delete it.
Or Just delete your node_modules folder and do `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

I had kind of the same issue 
 **Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js) ...**

Then I noticed that my node version was not compatible with my angular version, you can check it by doing `ng v` and if so, you will get a warning about that.

So I just changed my node version to a compatible one (in my case i had angular 14.3.0, so I switched from node 18.12.0 to 16.10.0) and had no longer the issue on new generated project. I assume that if you delete your node_modules folder (and dependencies?) and make a new `npm install`, it could work for the existing project.

*PS : To change easily your node version, you can install nvm (node version manager) so you can install a new one and switch easily. This is a link for windows version https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue the solution I found was:

1. delete the node_modules folder
2. delete package-lock.json
3. clear your NPM cache: npm cache clean --force
4. install again all dependencies: npm i

after that, all compile without any problem

Answer (score -1):

Check @angular/cdk in package.json

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).